# Custom fonts working on the app but not working on widgets

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I'm working on a widget app. I already implement my custom fonts on app and its working fine. But on my widgets, its not working at all. Both info.plist files includes all my fonts on 'Fonts provided by application' and I checked the build phases -> Copy Bundle Resources on both targets and its looking fine. Also all font targets checked on app and extension. I couldn't find any solution...

```
Text("Hello, World!").foregroundColor(.white).font(.custom("Poppins-ExtraLight", size: 20))
```

Here are my both Info.plist files, Copy Bundle Resources and Targets;

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... File formats in widgets Info.plist were tff not ttf... I changed them its working good.

Comment: "ttf not tff"? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: The file extensions used in the plist `.tff` didn't match the actual file extension on the font files `.ttf`.

Answer (score 1):

I had `UIAppFonts` only in my regular `Info.plist`. After adding it to `Info.plist` in Widget folder, the fonts were visible.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you put this somewhere in your widget hooks?

```
for familyName in UIFont.familyNames {
    print("\n-- \(familyName) \n")
    for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName) {
        print(fontName)
    }
}
```

Do you use the custom font in the app target in a UIKit or SwiftUI context?

Comment: This code printed the fonts in the computer but without my custom fonts. I installed them to computer also now but still not showing or printing my fonts. I'm using SwiftUI. Also added some screenshots now